# What are the Three Manifestations of Grace?

Tags: grace

I recently came across the phrase "Three Manifestations of Grace". The author used the phrase as if its meaning were common knowledge. As far as I can tell, some Christian writers do speak of three main types of Grace, but they do not necessarily agree on what they are. The clearest example I could find in terms of a denominational doctrine was from Methodism, which takes it [theology of grace from Wesley](https://www.umcdiscipleship.org/resources/foundations):

- Prevenient grace literally means "the grace that comes before." Prevenient grace calls us into a relationship with God before we are even aware of God. It prepares us for the dawning awareness that God loves us so much that God seeks us out first.
- Justifying grace offers reconciliation, forgiveness of sin, freedom from the power and guilt of sin, and the possibility of new relationships with God and with one another.
- Sanctifying grace enables us to grow into the image of Christ and to live as a sign of God’s reign among us. Sanctifying grace leads to inward and outward holiness.

Wesley's system owes much to Augustine, but I do not know if Catholic theology speaks of three types of grace per se. Also, I notice that writers of other denominations refer to different manifestations or stages of grace... sometimes numbering as high as fifteen.

What I'm really looking for is whether 1) prevenient, 2) sanctifying and 3) justifying grace are the most likely types of grace this writer was referring to. Related questions: Do other denominations - especially Catholicism - also formally refer to these three as the main types? Do some denominations use a different three-fold typology?

Comment: God's grace is manifold or variegated (1 Peter 4:10).  Limiting it to 3 (or 15) manifestations seems man-made...we tend to prefer categories rather than spectra.

Comment: Augustine, Aquinas, Luther, Calvin and Wesley will be disappointed to hear that they erred in that respect!

Answer (score 3):

**What are the Three Manifestations of Grace?**

Wesley‘s definitions of various graces are not the sole definitions of graces, at least for the Catholic Church. The three manifestations of grace as you call them are the main channels of grace wherein God manifests a life of grace within the faithful soul that desires to live a life of holiness.

For Catholicism there are a few different reasons for defining graces differently according to the type of graces one receives.

Here follows how the Catholic Church defines the term grace generally and in particular the different types of graces that exist:

> [**Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33791&randomterm=false)
>
> In biblical language the condescension or benevolence (Greek charis) shown by God toward the human race; it is also the unmerited gift proceeding from this benevolent disposition. Grace, therefore, is a totally gratuitous gift on which man has absolutely no claim. Where on occasion the Scriptures speak of grace as pleasing charm or thanks for favors received, this is a derived and not primary use of the term.
>
> As the Church has come to explain the meaning of grace, it refers to something more than the gifts of nature, such as creation or the blessings of bodily health. Grace is the supernatural gift that God, of his free benevolence, bestows on rational creatures for their eternal salvation. The gifts of grace are essentially supernatural. They surpass the being, powers, and claims of created nature, namely sanctifying grace, the infused virtues, the gifts of the Holy Spirit, and actual grace. They are the indispensable means necessary to reach the beatific vision. In a secondary sense, grace also includes such blessings as the miraculous gifts of prophecy or healing, or the preternatural gifts of freedom from concupiscence.
>
> The essence of grace, properly so called, is its gratuity, since no creature has a right to the beatific vision, and its finality or purpose is to lead one to eternal life.

> [**Actual Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=31646&randomterm=false)
>
> Temporary supernatural intervention by God to enlighten the mind or strengthen the will to perform supernatural actions that lead to heaven. Actual grace is therefore a transient divine assistance to enable man to obtain, retain, or grow in supernatural grace and the life of God.

> [**Justifying Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34425&randomterm=false)
>
> The grace by which a person is restored to God's friendship, either for the first time, as in baptism, or after baptism, as in the sacrament of penance.

> [**Sanctifying Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36272&randomterm=false)
>
> The supernatural state of being infused by God, which permanently inheres in the soul. It is a vital principle of the supernatural life, as the rational soul is the vital principle of a human being's natural life. It is not a substance but a real quality that becomes part of the soul substance. Although commonly associated with the possession of the virtue of charity, sanctifuing grace is yet distinct from this virtue. Charity, rather, belongs to the will, whereas sanctifying grace belongs to the whole soul, mind, will, and affections. It is called sanctifying grace because it makes holy those who possess the gift by giving them a participation in the divine life. It is zo_ (life), which Christ taught that he has in common with the Father and which those who are in the state of grace share.

> [**Efficacious Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33281&randomterm=false)
>
> The actual grace to which free consent is given by the will so that the grace produces its divinely intended effect. In the controversy between the Dominicans [led by Báñez (1528-1604)] and the Jesuits [led by Molina (1525-1600)] there was no agreement on what precisely causes an actual grace to become efficacious. In the Báñezian theory, the efficacy of such grace depends on the character of the grace itself; in the Molinist theory, it depends on the fact that it is given under circumstances that God foresees to be congruous with the dispositions of the person receiving the grace. In every Catholic theory, however, it is agreed that efficacious grace does not necessitate the will or destroy human freedom.

> [**Habitual Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33850&randomterm=false)

Constant supernatural quality of the soul which sanctifies a person inherently and makes him or her just and pleasing to God. Also called sanctifying grace or justifying grace.

> [**Gratuitous Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33805&randomterm=false)
>
> The free gift conferred on particular persons for the salvation of others. Technically called gratia gratis data (grace freely given), it is independent of the personal moral life or behavior of its possessor. To this class belong such gifts of grace as charismata (prophecy, gift of miracles, gift of tongues), the priestly power of consecration and absolution, and the hierarchial power of jurisdiction.

> [**Sacramental Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36183&randomterm=false)
>
> The grace conferred by the valid and fruitful reception of the sacraments. It may be one or more of several kinds: 1. sanctifying grace is communicated in baptism, penance and in anointing of the sick when needed; 2. sanctifying grace is always increased when a sacrament is received in the state of grace; 3. actual grace is given by all the sacraments, either actually at the time of reception or also by title as a person needs divine help; 4. the sacramental character is indelibly imprinted on the soul in baptism, confirmation, and the priesthood; and 5. a distinctive sacramental grace is imparted by each of the seven sacraments, corresponding to their respective purpose in the supernatural life of the soul.

> [**Sufficient Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36691&randomterm=false)
>
> Actual grace considered apart from the supernatural effect for which it was bestowed. It may therefore mean the grace that does not meet with adequate co-operation on the part of the human recipient, and then it is merely sufficient grace. It is enough to enable a person to perform a salutary act, but who freely declines to co-operate. Or it may simply mean the grace that gives one the power to accomplish a salutary action, as distinct from an efficacious grace, which secures that the salutary act is accomplished.

> [**Sanating Grace**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36268&randomterm=false)
>
> Divine grace in its function of healing (sanare, heal) the ravages of sin, original and personal, in human nature. The healing process affects both the mind and the will. Grace heals the will by giving strength to desire and accept the known will of God, and joy in its performance.

Grace, in general, is a supernatural gift of God to intellectual creatures (both men and angels) for their eternal salvation, whether the latter be furthered and attained through salutary acts or a state of holiness.

Comment: + 1 thanks for this answer. How does the concept of prevenient grace fit here? I notice that Aquinas doesn't much care for it, but does it have a place in the Catholic theology of grace?

Comment: @DanFefferman Prevenient grace is simply actual grace! Worded differently but the same in concept.